# Does anyone have good data on the evolution of the Persian Gulf from Sumerian to Modern Times?

Tags: historical, time-series, hydrology

So far I can't find good data on the evolution of the Persian Gulf silting up, only what it was in 6000 BP, and how it is now without anything in between. Is there any dataset (preferably vector) you can point me to?

An example of the Persian Gulf Shoreline 6000 BP
[image: Persian Gulf Shoreline 6000 BP]

Comment: Just to be sure, can you confirm you're asking about physical maps (i.e. shoreline, rivers, etc.), and not about political/cultural boundaries? I originally posted an answer about political/cultural boundaries, and deleted it because I realized that it was probably not what you were talking about (my bad).

Comment: One of the issues is that we actually do not know what the shoreline over time. We can only guess. This is something I went looking for years ago without any real satisfaction as to what we know and how. I've even seen some argue that the differences were negligible, at least compared to estimates that inform that map.